# Why is Access multiply two SUM by eachother?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum

For some unknown reason, the query multiply two SUM fields by each other:

**the tables**

```
products table
+----+--------+
| id | p_name |
+----+--------+
|  1 | name1  |
|  2 | name2  |
+----+--------+

warehouses table:
+----+------------+
| id |   w_name   |
+----+------------+
|  1 | warehouse1 |
|  2 | warehouse2 |
+----+------------+

intake table:
+--------------+------------+--------+
| warehouse_id | product_id | amount |
+--------------+------------+--------+
|            1 |          1 |     10 |
|            1 |          1 |     10 |
+--------------+------------+--------+

outtake table
+--------------+------------+--------+
| warehouse_id | product_id | amount |
+--------------+------------+--------+
|            1 |          1 |      5 |
|            1 |          1 |      5 |
+--------------+------------+--------+
```

**the query**

```
SELECT warehouses.w_name,
       products.p_name,
       Sum(intake.units_amout) AS intakeSum,
       Sum(outtake.amount) AS outtakeSum
FROM (warehouses
      INNER JOIN (products
                  INNER JOIN intake ON products.id = intake.product_id) ON warehouses.id = intake.warehouse_id)
INNER JOIN outtake ON (warehouses.id = outtake.warehouse_id)
AND (products.id = outtake.product_id)
GROUP BY warehouses.w_name,
         products.p_name;
```

**the result**

```
+--------------+------------+-----------+------------+
| warehouse_id | product_id | intakeSum | outtakeSum |
+--------------+------------+-----------+------------+
|            1 |          1 |        40 |         20 |
+--------------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

**the expected result**

```
+--------------+------------+-----------+------------+
| warehouse_id | product_id | intakeSum | outtakeSum |
+--------------+------------+-----------+------------+
|            1 |          1 |        20 |         10 |
+--------------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

if i add a third entry to intake (with the same product and warehouse ids), the "outtakeSum" will be multipy be 3! and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the join if the intake with the outtake table which will result in four total rows leading to a sum of 4*10=40 and 4*5=20.

In order to get around this, you could do two subqueries, one for the intake and outtake tables each that will summarize these tables for each warehouse_id/product_id pair.

i.e.:

```
SELECT warehouse_id, product_id, SUM(amount)
FROM intake
GROUP BY warehouse_id, product_id;
```

(and a similar query for the outtake table)

If you use these queries instead of intake & outtake for joining, it will work as intended.